# How can I print the first matched line using sed or grep?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, grep

I have a config file where each line is in a format say `UniqueOption = SomeValue`:

```
$ cat somefile  
option1sub1 = yes
option1sub2 = 1234
...
option1subn = xxxx
option2 = 2345
option3 = no
...
```

I want to deal with each value of "option1" in a loop. but, `sed` or `grep` give me all of option1 in one time.

How could I achieve that using `sed` or `grep`, getting a single option1 line at a time?

Comment: Post your efforts that you made in `sed` and `grep` and show us the exact output need for the input shown

Comment: What's wrong with getting all the relevant values at once? That would almost certainly be what you want. You definitely do not want to have to scan the file more than once.

Comment: `sed -n '/option1/,1p' settings.conf`

Comment: @Kusalananda actually, for example, I want to do something for 'yes' of 'option1sub1'. if I get all relevant values, I can pass each of them to different variable or program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pipe the output of `grep` to a `while` loop:

```
grep 'option1' somefile | while read line
  do
  echo "single option is in var $line"
  done
```

Comment: please explain the downvote. I answer in topic to question. The solution provided works, so what is the matter?

Answer (score 0):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `awk` may help you on same to get the value of `option1` string's last value.

```
awk -F" = " '/^option1/{print $NF}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Above will print all values of string `option1` in case you need only very first value of string `option1` then use following.

```
awk -F" = " '/^option1/{print $NF;exit}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will parse out all sub-options for `option1` in the file `file.conf` and save them in a `bash` array. The options are then easily accessed from that array.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r data; do
    opt1+=( "$data" )
done < <( awk -F ' *= *' '$1 ~ /^option1/ { print $2 }' file.conf )

printf 'Option 1, sub-option 1 is "%s"\n' "${opt1[0]}"
```

Output:

```
Option 1, sub-option 1 is "yes"
```

The `awk` script will return everything after the `=` (and any spaces), which allows you to store data that contains multiple words.  Only the lines starting with `option1` in the configuration file are processed.

This would be adapted to parse the whole configuration file into a single structure, possibly using an associative array in a sufficiently recent version of `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Already we can see few awesome answers but as you asked something with grep, you can use one of the following if you want.
For all values

```
grep option1 m | cut -d "=" -f2 | awk '{$1=$1};1'
```

For first value

```
grep option1 m | cut -d "=" -f2 | awk '{$1=$1};1' | head -1
```

Here: cut is used to cut the second option uisng dilimiter =; awk is used to trim the spaces in output and head is used to print first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed '/^option1.* = /!d;s///' somefile
```

With gnu grep 2.20 (support of pcre)

```
grep -oP '^option1.* = \K.*' somefile
```

If you want to get only the first match

```
sed '/^option1.* = /!d;s///;q' somefile

grep -m1 -oP '^option1.* = \K.*' somefile
```